# Java mySQL with 000webhost

Tags: java, mysql

I created a mySQL database on 000webhost and I wanted to connect it into my Java program but somehow driver aren't receiving sockets. Here is my code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql2.000webhost.com/a4931569_users/Users", username, pass);
```

where a4931569_users is database, Users is table. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure mysql2.000webhost.com server is listening on the desired port. And also whether the server is configured to accept the connections from outside world?>

Comment: you do not need to provide table name. just point to the database.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: 000webhost.com has disabled the feature of connecting from a remote computer. Hence even if your syntax is correct you can't connect to the database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL from 000webhost doesn't allow you to connect from external applications, just from within pages hosted in their domain.

Please check: [How can I connect to MySQL from my computer?](http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=27)

Comment: It is possible that it is not allowed to connect it no it is not possible. I think here is he want to give the table name and if they give only database name then it is fine...

Comment: Do you know any other free mySQL database host?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I really like the 000webhost, despite this little concern.

Comment: Any other alternative of 000webhost?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that **mysql2.000webhost.com** URL allows remote connection for the specified user or not. If it allows **then there can be some problem with database driver jar file** either its missing or not compatible with database version.

Answer (score 0):

As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for the `DriverManager#getConnection()` method says:

> Attempts to establish a connection to the given database URL.

Therefore, remove the `Users` table name from the provided URL and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the table name from the connection string.

just write

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql2.000webhost.com/a4931569_users", username, pass);
```

JDBC URL Format

The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
[?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
```

If the host name is not specified, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. If the port is not specified, it defaults to 3306, the default port number for MySQL servers.

```
jdbc:mysql://[host:port],[host:port].../[database] »
[?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
```

Here is a sample connection URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true
```

Please refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

**Edit**

In case of

`It says: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

you need to go with answer of Math.

MySQL from 000webhost doesn't allow you to connect from external applications, just from within pages hosted in their domain.

Please check: [How can I connect to MySQL from my computer?](http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=27)

Comment: It still doesn't work. It says:
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure